# How can I assign unique IDs to buttons in a for loop in a Django template?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I am attempting to assign a unique ID to a button by including the ID of a post in the button's ID. However, I am unable to properly reference this button ID in an AJAX function. As a result, the button is not producing any output when clicked. Could you please provide guidance on how to correctly call the button ID in the AJAX function and resolve this issue? The relevant template file is 'postlist'.

postlist template:

```
{% csrf_token %}
     {% for post in object_list.all %}
     <div class="cardbox">
      <div class="cardbox-heading">
       <!-- START dropdown-->
       <div class="dropdown pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-flat btn-flat-icon" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
         <em class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></em>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-scale dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(-136px, 28px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hide post</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Stop following</a>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Report</a>
        </div>
       </div><!--/ dropdown -->
       <!-- END dropdown-->
       <div class="media m-0">
        <div class="d-flex mr-3">
         <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="{{post.username.avatar.url}}" alt="User"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
         <p class="m-0">{{post.username}}</p>
         <small><span>{{post.create_date|timesince}}</span></small>
        </div>
       </div><!--/ media -->
      </div><!--/ cardbox-heading -->
      <div class="cardbox-item">
       <a href="{% url 'posts:post_detail_final' pk=post.pk slug=post.slug %}" data-toggle="modal">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{post.image_data.url}}" alt="MaterialImg">
       </a> 
      </div><!--/ cardbox-item -->
      <div class="cardbox-base">
       <ul>
            {% for likes in post.likes.all %}
                <li ><a href="{% url 'profiles:detail' username=likes.username %}"><img src="{{likes.userprofile.avatar.url}}" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="User"></a></li>
            {% endfor %}  
       </ul>
      </div><!--/ cardbox-base -->
        <div class="cardbox-like">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="" id="like_count{{post.id}}">{{post.likes.count}}</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-link text-dark p-0 border-0 btn-outline-light" id="like-button{{post.id}}" value="{{post.id}}">
                    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'posts:post_detail_final' pk=post.pk slug=post.slug %}"> <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> <span>{{post.comments.count}}</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/ cardbox-like -->                  
     </div><!--/ cardbox -->
     {% endfor %}
```

Ajax

```
     <script>

 
  $(document).on('click', '#like-button{{post.id}}', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{% url "posts:like" %}',
      data: {
        postid: $('#like-button{{post.id}}').val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        action: 'post'
      },
      success: function (json) {
        document.getElementById("span[id^=like_count]").innerHTML = json['result']
      },
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
      }
    });
  })
</script>
```

If more code is require than tell me in a comment session ,i will update my question with that information.

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).on('click', 'button[id^=like-button]'` and then `postid: $(this).val()`

Comment: Nope i didn't try, you can edit my question with the changes you said.

Comment: I could change your question but then other people can't see your original code, so i should not. It should be fairly easy to see what needs to be changed. `$(document).on('click', '#like-button{{post.id}}', function (e) {` -> `$(document).on('click', 'button[id^=like-button]', function(e) {` AND `postid: $('#like-button{{post.id}}').val()` -> `postid: $(this).val()`

Comment: Thanks this is working fine but i also want to give different postid to the like_count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use classes:

```html
<button class="like-button" value="{{post.id}}" ...>...</button>
```

then

```js
  $(document).on('click', '.like-button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let post_id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{% url "posts:like" %}',
      data: {
        postid: post_id,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        action: 'post'
      },
      success: function (json) {
        // document.getElementById("like_count").innerHTML = json['result']
        $("#like_count" + post_id).html(json['result']);
      },
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
      }
    });
  })
</script>
```

inside the event callback the `$(this)` is the `.like-button` you clicked on

Comment: Can you tell me about like_count ,that how can i get that span id with name like_count with postid as shown in a code , Want to use that in a success function post can i get that ?

Comment: @AhmedYasin You mean like this? `success: function (json) { $("#like_count" + post_id).html(json['result']); },` where the var post_id is the one you defined with `let post_id = $(this).val();`
I edited the answer, it's more readable there